My feature file is unable to recognise step definition package, not sure what's wrong ? Giving error "Undefined step reference"
I think the issue is mostly with my runner class where the glue parameter is not recognising the stepdefinition package, i have double checked everything not sure what's wrong.
I have also tried giving relative path like:- str/test/java/stepdefinitions
RunnerClass:-
package runners;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefinitions"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"}
)
public class TestRunner {
}

stepDefinition java file:-
package stepdefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

public class CurrencyConversionStepDefs {

    private Response response;
    @Given("I have a valid API endpoint")
    public void i_have_a_valid_api_endpoint() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD";
    }

    @io.cucumber.java.en.When("^I make a GET request to the API$")
    public void i_make_a_get_request_to_the_api() {
        response = RestAssured.get();
    }

    @Then("the API call is successful")
    public void the_api_call_is_successful() {
        response.then().statusCode(200);
    }

    @Then("the status code is {int}")
    public void the_status_code_is(Integer statusCode) {
        response.then().statusCode(statusCode);
    }

    @Then("the response contains a valid price")
    public void the_response_contains_a_valid_price() {
        response.then().body("rates", Matchers.notNullValue());
    }

Feature File:-
Feature: Currency Conversion API Testing

  Scenario: Verify successful API call and valid price
    Given I have a valid API endpoint
    When I make a GET request to the API
    Then the API call is successful
    And the status code is 200
    And the response contains a valid price

Below is my project structure:-

Update 1:-
I recreated the whole project, this time the compiler is recognising the steps, using command + click I am able to reach to the definitions but when I run them it asks me to implement the steps, i am so puzzled.



Nothing wrong with your project setup. But it does look like IDEA doesn't recognize your project. Does it work with mvn test?

No with maven i am getting other errors, I recreated the whole project, this time the compiler is recognising the steps, using command + click I am able to reach to the definitions but when I run them it asks me to implement the steps, i am so puzzled.

When using IDEA, Cucumber runs through io.cucumber.core.cli.Main. When using JUnit it runs through TestRunner. These are different systems with their own configuration. Check the run configuration in IDEA. Or solve your maven problems.

I have checked the configuration, it looks fine. I have attached the screenshot in the body of the question description, can you please take a look?

I don't see anything wrong. I think it would be better to focus on Maven. You can also use this project. It has 1 implemented step and 2 undefined steps.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton
